# How to replace NaNs with some change in previous values in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

```
    0    1     2
0   10   20   30
1   40   NaN  60
2   50   55   90
3   60   NaN  80
4   70   75   90
```

What I need to do is replace every NaN value with 30 , 65 respectively. That means ten added to previous value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can **[`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)** the dataframe and then add 10 , then **[`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)** with that df:

```
df = df.fillna(df.shift().add(10))
# for a new df :-> new_df = df.fillna(df.shift().add(10))
```

---

```
print(new_df)

    0     1   2
0  10  20.0  30
1  40  30.0  60
2  50  55.0  90
3  60  65.0  80
4  70  75.0  90
```

**Note**: If you have both numeric and string columns, you can first select only numeric columns using **[`df.select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html)**  and then do the operation:

```
num_df = df.select_dtypes(np.number)
df.loc[:,num_df.columns] = num_df.fillna(num_df.shift().add(10))
```

If you want to create a new df and not modify the original one then use **[`df.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)** to assign the new values to the subset of columns:

```
new_df = df.assign(**num_df.fillna(num_df.shift().add(10)))
```

Comment: ThnakYou @anky . Your answer helped me.. first code gave me an error.```" can concatenate only str(not int) to str```. Then i tried your your second code. it worked

Comment: @ElezabethJose That is because the second solution used only numerical columns.Glad I could help. If my answer helped solving your question, please consider accepting my answer by clicking on the grey tick mark to the left of the answer to make it green tick, so as to close the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this as well:

```
df = df.fillna(df.fillna(method='ffill').add(10))
```

I find this method easier.